# Matplotlib pcolor chart with dates gives error: "DateFormatter found a value of x=0", but date is non-zero

Tags: date, matplotlib, date-formatting

I am having issue with DateFormatter found a value of x=0 even though dates should be properly transformed via mdates.date2num() and instructing dates on x. Any help would be great! Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import subplot
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, 2)),
                      index=['2006-02-16',
                             '2006-02-17', '2006-02-18'])
df_tmp.index = pd.to_datetime(df_tmp.index)
t_num = mdates.date2num(df_tmp.index)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
ax = subplot(111)
c = ax.pcolor(t_num, np.arange(2), df_tmp.T)
date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%D')
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(10))
ax.set_yticklabels([f'my_label {i}' for i in np.arange(10)])
f.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Most bizarrely, when I run the snippet above as a separate piece of code, it works fine, but when embedded in another piece of code I get the error.

[image]

Is there anything that could interfere? I am also using:

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

just in case. Thanks for any help!

(Note in code I changed f -> f2 just in case it interfered with other figures previously referenced as f)

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer

```
plt.close('all')
```

did the trick. Not fully clear why though. Any further insight would be great.